# Probability density function dependent variable probability

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So if $f(x,y) = 8xy$ with $0<x<y<1$.

Now how would I find $P(Y<0.5)$?  I have no idea how to do it since $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other, how would you get a numerical value since all your bounds contain a variable in them? I see no way of getting a numerical value since the bound for $x$ is $0<x < y$ and the bound for $y$ is $x < y < 0.5$.

Comment: You have the joint density, so just integrate.  $x\in [0,.5],y\in [x,.5]$.

Comment: @sid Yeah what I said in the post is correct. I get $\frac{1}{16}$ when I do it lulu's way. Is that not right?

Comment: I get $\frac 1{16}$ as well.  I don't see any problem.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read @lulu's comment properly. I initially read it as $x \in [0, .5],y\in[0,.5]$. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $P(Y<1/2)$ you need to integrate $f(x,y)$ over all $(x,y)$ where 
$y<1/2$ (yellow region in picture below). Since $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)$ outside
the green triangle, the correct way to set up the double integral is 
$$P(Y<1/2)=\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^y 8xy\, dx\,dy.$$
Can you take it from here?

[image]